# Find similar strings in list and count them - maybe existing software?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem. So I have there an excel list in the following format:

```
Columbia University           | YES 
Washington University         | YES 
University of Columbia        | NO 
Columbia Uni                  | NO 
Columbia University, New York | YES 
Washington Uni                | NO 
Columbia University           | YES 
University of Washington      | YES 
Washington University         | YES 
Washington Uni                | NO
```

The result should be the following

```
Columbia University | 3 X YES 
Washington University | 3 X YES
```

The challenge is now to tell the program/software that these different strings which represent the same university are actually the SAME. Do you have a idea of a program which learns automatically. Maybe give the program user also some suggestions like: This might be Columbia University, right?

It would be great if someone has a solution for that. I really don't mind if you know an existing program which could solve the problem? That would be even better!

Thank you so much for your help!

Manuel

Comment: Does it have to be done solely within Excel?

Comment: You are going to have to develop some pretty specific rules or use a lookup table as suggested by @user3578951.  For example, why are you treating `Washington University` and `University of Washington` as being the same?  One is in St. Louis, MO; and the other is in Seattle, WA ??  `Columbia University` is in NYC, NY and `University of Columbia` might be equivalent to the `University of British Columbia`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - good question/point.  I think a lookup table, in the long run, would be a good thing to get started on.  Otherwise, you run the risk of mixing colleges up.

Comment: The best solution will be to control the data, perhaps with a drop-down instead of a custom field. Failing that, you will need to develop rules and also use a lookup table.  In your other comments, you have rejected the lookup table, and you have not provided any rules for proceeding.  You need to step back and figure out how you would do this without a computer; pay particular attention to dealing with the potential conflicts I mentioned in my previous comment above.

Comment: drop-down is not possible...we talk about 20 different sources of data...email,web everything...which rules do you want to provide me?

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking, you could have a helper table where you list unique colleges in one column, and the "actual equivalent" in a cell to the right of it.  IE:

```
Columbia University     Columbia University
Columbia Uni            Columbia University
Washington Uni          Washington University
Washington University   Washington University
```

and just use something like Vlookup to return the "Actual" college.  Is that too much? It won't exactly "learn", but it'll get you going in the mean time.  As you get more and more colleges/names, your list will be more robust.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Its a good idea but too much work, I think we have at least 5-10 different writings for a university name and also over 100 universities which means the helper table would be too big!

Manuel

Comment: I'm not sure if you're familiar with vlookup or tables in Excel, but a vlookup table of say 100 rows isn't that big.

I also assume you have no control of the way the data is generated and given to you? I.e. you can't ask the people sending you those to make sure the university names are "complete"...?

Comment: unfortunately I have no control on how I get the data of the universities its a custom field...

Answer (score 0):

Set out your data as below for column A and B

```
Col A                         |Col B|Col C|Col D     |Col E 
Columbia University           |  YES|YES  |Columbia  |3
Washington University         |  YES|YES  |Washington|3
University of Columbia        |  NO |NO   | 
Columbia Uni                  |  NO |NO   |             
Columbia University, New York |  YES|YES  |         
Washington Uni                |  NO |NO   |         
Columbia University           |  YES|YES  |             
University of Washington      |  YES|YES  |             
Washington University         |  YES|YES  |             
Washington Uni                |  NO |NO   |
```

Then in Col C use

```
=TRIM(B1)
```

Then in Col D write the university names, in column E use below

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*" &D1&"*",C:C,"YES")
```